# Highlight selected row in DataTable using keyTable extension

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a table and I would like the users to navigate using the up/down arrow keys, this part is accomplished using the keyTable extension of the Datables.

I would also like the table row that contains the focused cell to be highlighted. I have tried this code which should add the class `selected` to the row which should in turn highlight it but it does not.

```
table
    .on( 'key-focus', function ( e, datatable, cell ) {
        var row = datatable.row( cell.index().row );
        $( row.node() ).addClass( "selected" );
    } );
```

Fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/hqxq7dk1/

Comment: You need add css rule: https://jsfiddle.net/hqxq7dk1/3/

Comment: not to argue since your suggestion works but I thought the `selected` class is defined somewhere in bootstrap.

Comment: It may be better to use `Select` extension: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/ [ https://jsfiddle.net/hqxq7dk1/4/ ]

Comment: the row does not highlight (in Chrome) any more.

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure if SO notifies OP of edits to answers or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bootstrap tables, the class is not `selected` rather you probably want `active`. (Though I guess any [contextual class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) will work.)

I'm using DataTables v1.10.10 and I too need the selected row highlighted. I believe I've pulled out the relevant code:

```
    $('#MY_TABLE tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            table.$('tr.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    }
```

Above sets up an event listener for a click on a row. The `active` class is removed from whatever row had been active and added to the row that received the click event.

**Edit** I forgot to consider that you mentioned you want to highlight the row using keyboard navigation and not a mouse click. So my answer is not 100% on point, though I think it will resolve the issue you are raising. If you cannot adapt above to your needs, let me know and I'll come up with a more specific reply.

**Edit 2**

Please see [this modification](https://jsfiddle.net/g9gkpbnx/1/) to your original fiddle. It is working fine with the Bootstrap contextual classes. This time, I'm using `.info`.

The modifications I made:

1. Moved the resources to the resource panel. (I only did this because it is recommended by the site to do it this way and I didn't recognize the displayed table as having Bootstrap styling so I thought there may have been an error linking the resource. There wasn't.)
2. I edited original markup to use the Bootstrap classes.

   ```
       <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" width="100%">
   ```
3. And as mentioned, I used the Bootstrap `info` class and added a JavaScript line to remove the class from the previously selected row before adding it to the current row:

   ```
       table.$('tr.info').removeClass('info');
       $( row.node() ).addClass( "info" );`
   ```

Point two is the key to getting it to work -- that is, using the Bootstrap CSS rules throughout. (That and removing the class from the prior active row.) I realize this answer results in a change to your styling which you may not appreciate. But it answers your question why you have to define a `select` rule and presumably you are using Bootstrap because you like their styling choices.

Comment: so far I am using the solution that @stdob offered; using a new class. I tried your suggestion in the fiddle I provided but it does not highlight the row.

Comment: sorry for the late response. juggling projects. thank you for the thorough explanation. I think you should emphasize in your answer that the styles are at fault and that `daTatable` classes and `bootstrap` classes do not play nice together; something I did not see in the documentation of the `dataTables`.

Comment: @gaitat -I don't think that's the way to think about it, that they don't play nicely together. In fact, I think it's the opposite! The DataTables plugin has a native look and feel. However, it also supports, other styles, for example, Bootstrap and Foundation. Think of the css file that is linked in as a skin. By linking in the Bootstrap "skin", the developer can continue to use the Bootstrap classes and ignore the native DataTable classes. If they weren't working well together, a developer would have to use the native class names to get the Bootstrap look. I agree, the docs could be explicit.